# Replicate Row Number with older version of MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, row-number

Is there a nice way in MySQL (older version) to replicate the SQL Server function ROW_NUMBER()?

I am trying to find 2 most used categories with their usage count per day using this query but ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION are not available in my old version of SQL.

```
Select a.* 
FROM
( SELECT 
     dDay,
     category,
     COUNT(*) as CountOfCategory,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dDay ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS intRow
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY category, dDate ) as a
WHERE intRow <= 2
ORDER BY dDay,
         intRow;
```

There is a variation of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql) but `COUNT(*)` in my query does not seem to fit the solutions there.

Input

| dDay | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | car |
| 2 | bike |
| 2 | car |
| 1 | car |
| 3 | truck |
| 1 | bike |
| 1 | car |
| 3 | car |
| 3 | car |
| 2 | bike |
| 1 | bike |
| 2 | truck |
| 2 | truck |
| 2 | truck |

Expected Output: Top 2 categories (with their total count) per day

| dDay | Category | CountOfCategory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | car | 3 |
| 1 | bike | 2 |
| 2 | bike | 2 |
| 2 | truck | 2 |
| 3 | car | 2 |
| 3 | truck | 1 |

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected output and specific MySQL version.

Comment: *For example* This is wrong example. Synthactically wrong. If you'll disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY it become logically wrong.

Comment: @FaNo_FN More details added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to find 2 most used categories with their usage count per day using this query but ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION are not available in my old version of SQL.

In older versions of MySQL, I think the simplest solution is to put the categories in a single column, using two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT dDay,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(category, ':', CountOfCategory ORDER BY CountOfCategory DESC), ',', 2)
FROM (SELECT dDay, category, COUNT(*) as CountOfCategory,
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY category, dDate
     ) cd
GROUP BY dDay;
```

Hopefully, this will be sufficient until you are able to upgrade to a more modern version of MySQL.

EDIT:

You can actually do what you want using variables:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM (SELECT cd.*,
             (@rn := if(@d = dDay, @rn + 1,
                        if(@d := dDay, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT dDay, category, COUNT(*) as CountOfCategory,
            FROM Table1
            GROUP BY category, dDate
            ORDER BY dDate, COUNT(*) DESC
           ) cd CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @d := -1, @rn := 0) params
      ) cd
WHERE rn <= 2
ORDER BY dDate, rn;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for these solutions. Exactly what I was looking for.